# A good substitute for ASMX web service methods, but not a general handler

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, exception, pagemethods

The best thing I like about ASP.NET MVC, is that you can directly call a server method (called action), from the client. This is so convenient, and so straightforward, that I really like to implement such a model in ASP.NET WebForms too.

However, in ASP.NET WebForms, to call a server method from the client, you should either use **[Page Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163480.aspx)**, or Web Services, both of which use SOAP as their communication protocol (though JSON can also be used).

There is also another substitution, which is using Generic Handlers. The problem with them however is that, a separate Generic Handler should be written for each server method. In other words, each Generic Handler works like a simple method.

Is there anyway else to imitate MVC model in ASP.NET WebForms?

Please note that I can't change to MVC platform right now, cause the project at our hand is a big project and we don't have required resources and time to change our platform. What we seek, is a simple MVC model implementation for our AJAX calls. A problem that we have with Web Services, is the [known problem of SoapException](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/keith/archive/2005/06/02/9712.aspx), and we're not interested in creating [custom SoapExctensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw638yk.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can mix ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Webforms in the same project.  You'll just need to add the correct MVC parts to your current Webforms project and have the best of both worlds.

http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/general/mixing-asp-net-mvc-and-webforms has a good walkthrough of all the steps you'll need to take to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can splice your asp.net webforms app with something like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) perhaps?

I've had great success with Nancy and [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) after I abandoned the horrible Ajax Control Toolkit.

(Apologies if I have misunderstood your question - I read it twice)